# Get specified line from file using php

Tags: php

how can get specified lines from file

```php
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode(',', $line_of_text);

    //from line   01 to line 100  echo "Lines 1";
    //from line   100 to line 200  echo "Lines 2";
    //from line   400 to line 1000  do somthing
}       

fclose($file_handle);
```

I need this output

> //from line   400 to line 1000  do somthing
>
> //from line   100 to line 200  do somthing

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit vague. But if `$parts` variable are where you keep your lines, then in this case you can use function [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) to pick only lines that you're interested in.

For example:

```
$parts = file('yourfile.txt');
$parts1to100 = array_slice($parts, 1, 100);
$parts100to400 = array_slice($parts, 100, 300);
$parts400to1000 = array_slice($parts, 400, 600);
```

If you'll need more separate parts, then that would be a different case and might be better to create a separate function which accepts certain values and returns required parts without relying on multiple variables. But that's a different story.

Comment: Not work i have in file.txt   data1,data2   and need get data1 from line 1 to line 100 for example. Thanks

Comment: @JeanPatrik, added file reading part. However I'm not quire sure I understand what's the problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks sir solved with code    ` $lines = file('yourfile'); for($i =399; $i < 1000; $i++){ echo $lines[$i];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function to pull each line of your file into an array. Then use a [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop to iterate through the lines you want.

Example:

```
$lines = file('yourfile'); 
for($i =399; $i < 1000; $i++){ 
     echo $lines[$i];
}
```